# Java 9: 'opens' module for access by reflection not required?

Tags: java, reflection, module

The `opens` keyword in the logic of Java modules allows reflective access ([here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/reflective-access.html)). I've recently ported a complex JavaFX app. to Java 15 with success, but it was a nightmare because JavaFX is rightly based on reflective access.

My question is about a more simple Java 15 application **THAT PERFECTLY WORKS**, but **I expected a runtime error** that **DID NOT OCCUR**! Why? Any highlight welcome... So, I have a very common client/server relationship between 2 modules as follows:

```java
module PauWare2 {
   exports com.pauware.pauware_engine.Core;
}

module My_device_module {
   requires PauWare2;
}
```

One may observe that `opens` **IS NOT** used in `My_device_module`. In practice, `PauWare2` accesses public methods by reflection:

```java
package My_device_package;

public class My_device { // In 'My_device_module'
   public void a() {}
   com.pauware.pauware_engine.Core.AbstractStateMachine _My_device_state_machine;
   // Reflective access of 'a' method by '_My_device_state_machine':
  _My_device_state_machine.launchByReflection(this, "a");
}
```

I expected a runtime error, which involves `opens My_device_package to PauWare2;` in `My_device_module`? However, as said, no problem at all... Any idea on that? THANKS in advance..

Comment: Only "deep reflection" - accessing stuff that is not normally accessible - is forbidden. `a()` is public.

Comment: After reading your question multiple times, I realized that it’s not clear what is accessing what in which way. A *variable* of the class `My_device` is accessing a method of the class `My_device` inside the class `My_device` but somehow within the other module? Provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual access that you think should not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Compare with the Java Language Specification:

> #### [7.7.2. Exported and Opened Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.2)
>
> The `exports` directive specifies the name of a package to be exported by the current module. For code in other modules, this grants access at compile time and run time to the `public` and `protected` types in the package, and the `public` and `protected` members of those types ([§6.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)). It also grants reflective access to those types and members for code in other modules.
>
> The `opens` directive specifies the name of a package to be opened by the current module. For code in other modules, this grants access at run time, but not compile time, to the `public` and `protected` types in the package, and the `public` and `protected` members of those types. It also grants reflective access to all types in the package, and all their members, for code in other modules.

So the point of the `opens` directive is *not* that it grants reflective access, `exports` does that too. The point of using `opens` instead of `exports` is not granting compile-time access, which implies that *only* reflective access at runtime will be possible¹.

Therefore, when you export a package anyway, there is no need for an additional `opens`. It implies that if you can access something directly, you can also access it reflectively.

¹ or, taking the specification literally, class files not generated by compiling standard Java source code could access the opened types and members at runtime.

---

The article you’ve linked, is about “deep reflection”, getting access to a member by calling [`setAccessible(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)). But even the cited documentation says:

> This method may be used by a caller in class `C` to enable access to a [`member`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Member.html) of [`declaring class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#getDeclaringClass()) `D` if any of the following hold:
>
> - `C` and `D` are in the same module.
> - The member is `public` and `D` is `public` in a package that the module containing `D` [`exports`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#isExported(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module)) to at least the module containing `C`.
> - The member is `protected static`, `D` is `public` in a package that the module containing `D` exports to at least the module containing `C`, and `C` is a subclass of `D`.
> - `D` is in a package that the module containing `D` [`opens`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#isOpen(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module)) to at least the module containing `C`. All packages in unnamed and open modules are open to all modules and so this method always succeeds when `D` is in an unnamed or open module.

So, the second bullet makes it clear that you also can use `setAccessible(true)` for `public` members of `public` types of exported packages.

The relevant difference is in the next section:

> This method cannot be used to enable access to private members, members with default (package) access, protected instance members, or protected constructors when the declaring class is in a different module to the caller and the package containing the declaring class is not open to the caller's module.

So it only makes a difference for non-`public` members, especially `private` and default (package) access.

Comment: I verified that packages that are neither exported nor opened can *not* get accessed by another module. And you did *not* show how the reflective access it done. You added an invocation of a method `launchByReflection` whose code is not included, at a location where method invocations are not even possible in real source code. As said, provide a [mcve], not some fragments of pseudo code.

Comment: You may compare with [these steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZVZF.gif) to see where your attempt to check the behavior of accessing an unexported package differs. A common error is using a class path, in other words, not using modules at all.

Comment: This thread is closed because my initial question comes from a misuse of NetBeans (12.0) (and Maven?). To sum up, Holger is right. We need 'opens' to access a module by reflection. The problem in NetBeans is that *EXECUTION SUCCEEDS* while 'opens' *IS NOT USED*. Trying the same with the command line leads to a different behavior (ie, Holger demonstration). So, try to investigate the problem within NetBeans...

Comment: @Holger What about _services_? `module U { uses S; }`, `module P { provides S with I; }`. Despite neither exporting nor opening anything, I am able to inspect annotations on `I` from within `U`. Where is this covered by the JLS?

Comment: @SebastianS you can inspect the annotations of *any* class.